# Count number of similar items in two lists using functional programming

Tags: list, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have two lists with same size: `list1`, `list2`.

I want to return count of matching elements on the same index:

```
int count=0;
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
    if(list1[i] == list2[i])count++;
}
return count;
```

How to do this with any functional language? To be more specific, how to do this with `ramda.js`.

Comment: find some version of `zipWith`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two examples:

```
R.pipe(R.zipWith(R.equals), R.filter(R.identity), R.length);
R.pipe(R.zipWith(R.equals), R.reduce(R.add, 0));
```

Comment: Elegant solutions!